# Mac OSX - Mobilefirst Test Workbench - Not able to connect to a device

Tags: macos, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-mtw

Need assistance please on the error that im encountering in Mobilefirst test workbench.

I was not able to connect to a device due to this error:

Warning: RTW has not been successfully started; this may prevent device connection.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: "see Error Log for more details." How much clearer can it be?

Answer (score -1):

You could have an occupied port that prevents the server from starting? Maybe the instructions here will help: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21678980

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.